# Reading lines in captured stdout in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to capture stdout and then parse it after calling a function. I am doing so by means of a cStringIO.StringIO object but the readline call yields nothing. I have created below test to show you what's happening:

```
import cStringIO, sys

def readstream(s):
    c = s.getvalue()
    for i in c.split('\n'):
        yield i

old_stdout = sys.stdout
stream = cStringIO.StringIO()
sys.stdout = stream

print ('testing this stuff')
print ('more testing of this')

sys.stdout = old_stdout

print 'getvalue:'
print stream.getvalue()

print 'readlines:'
for line in stream.readlines():
    print line

print 'readstream:'
for line in readstream(stream):
    print line
```

The generated output is:

```
getvalue:
testing this stuff
more testing of this

readlines:
readstream:
testing this stuff
more testing of this
```

How is it that the stream.readlines() is yielding nothing?

thanks

Comment: There's really nothing specific to captured stdout here, and it adds extra complication that many readers may not understand. You'd have the exact same question if you just used `stream.write` or `print >>stream` instead, and it would be a more generally useful question.

Comment: @abarnert you are right, the problem was not about stdout, but I did not know about it when I wrote the question. I have used readlines in previous occasions and it worked fine, so I thought it was something specific to stdout redirection. Thus, the title refers to stdout. After checking your answer, it's obvious that it has nothing to do with stdout but with file IO management, but anyway, it's a problem that some rookie like me may encounter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just finished writing into `stream`, so its file pointer is at the end of the file.

`readlines` returns all lines from the current file pointer until the end of the file. Since there are no lines from the end of the file to the end of the file, it returns no lines.

If you want to move the file pointer back to the start of the file, use the [`seek`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) method:

```
print 'readlines:' # will print nothing
stream.seek(0)
for line in stream.readlines():
    print line
```

---

A few side notes:

First, [there is almost never a good reason to use `readlines()`](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html), and especially not in this case. A file is *already* an iterable of the lines in the file; there's no reason to create a list of the same lines just to iterate it. This will give you the exact same result:

```
stream.seek(0)
for line in stream:
    print line
```

… but simpler, faster, and without wasting memory.

Second, your `readstream` function is more complicated than it needs to be. Normally, generators yielding values have advantages over lists—they let your caller start working on the values as soon as each one is available instead of waiting until they're all done, they don't waste memory building a list just to iterate over it, etc. But in this case, you're already building a list by calling `split`, so you might as well just return it:

```
def readstream(s):
    c = s.getvalue()
    return c.split('\n')
```

Comment: Before launching the question, I tried to do this very same thing by closing and opening the stream again. Closing was easy, but then the method open was not available in cStringIO. Now reading your answer seems quite straightforward. Thanks!

Comment: @victor: Well, with a real file, you can close it and open a new file with it the same pathname. (Unless the file's been unlinked or replaced, of course!) With a StringIO, there's no pathname; the equivalent would be closing it and creating a new StringIO with the old one's `getvalue()`… but that would be kind of a silly thing to do.

Comment: I have now removed readlines from my python list of useful commands. Thanks for this a-bit-off-topic info.