# How to print output in a clear format as it gets print on command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming

- I am trying to SSH into a client, and to run a command, however the output is not formatted as it is shown on the CLI of the server.
- I have tried to use print function and tried to write to a file and checked numerous articles, but I guess I am missing something to look for.

  ```
  import paramiko
  import sys

  hn = "valid IP Address"  #hostname of the client
  ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh_client.connect (hostname = hn,username='randomUsername',password='randomPassword')
  print ("Connected to %s \n" % (hn))

  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("ping 8.8.8.8 -c 4")
  stdout = stdout.readlines()
  print (stdout)

  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("ping 8.8.4.4 -c 4")
  stdout = stdout.readlines()
  print (stdout)
  ```
- How can I print the output as like this AND write to a file? 
  Current output is like this

  ```
  ['PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.\n', '64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=57 time=21.3 ms\n', '64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=57 time=21.0 ms\n', '64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=57 time=21.0 ms\n', '64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=57 time=21.2 ms\n', '\n', '--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---\n', '4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms\n', 'rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.041/21.173/21.313/0.159 ms\n']
  ['PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.\n', '64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_req=1 ttl=57 time=19.4 ms\n', '64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_req=2 ttl=57 time=19.1 ms\n', '64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_req=3 ttl=57 time=18.8 ms\n', '64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_req=4 ttl=57 time=19.0 ms\n', '\n', '--- 8.8.4.4 ping statistics ---\n', '4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms\n', 'rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.819/19.135/19.470/0.233 ms\n']
  ```
- However I need it to printed like this

  ```
  ping 8.8.8.8
  PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=3.79 ms
  64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=3.58 ms
  64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=14.8 ms
  64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=3.37 ms
  --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
  4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms 
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.375/6.409/14.891/4.899 ms
  ```

Thank you for your help.

**** solved **** 
for i in stdout:
    print (i)

Comment: This `for i in stdout: print(i);`?

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over all elements of a list? Then you can solve it quite easily yourself. And if you don't know how to do that, then please study some more.

Comment: Yes. I agree, I need to study more! I am on my way for it! Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stdout is a list of strings - iterate over it and print each string instead of printing the whole list.

```
for i in stdout:
    print(i) # you can add end='' if you want to remopve the double spacing -> print(i, end='')
```

To write to a file i suggests starting with python documentation on [reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be :

```
print(stdout.getvalue())
```

More explanations on readlines() vs getvalue() can be found in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18758739/18048269